# Change the value in a column of a dataframe depending on how many of each possible value there are

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
chr <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
b1 <- c('HP', 'HP', 'CP', 'CP', 'KP')
b2 <- c('HP', 'HP', 'CP', 'CP', 'KP')
b3 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'HP', 'CP')
b4 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'HP', 'CP')
b5 <- c('CP', 'CP', 'KP', 'KP', 'HP')
b6 <- c('CP', 'CP', 'KP', 'KP', 'HP')
b7 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'HP', 'CP', 'CP')
b8 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'HP', 'CP', 'CP')
df <- data.frame(chr, b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
```

I want to write a function that looks at each 'b' column and asks if it contains the value 'HP'. If it does, and the other six 'b' columns contain 'CP' or 'KP', I want to change the value 'HP' into 'CP' or 'KP' depending on which is the majority. If CP is the majority, change the HP to CP. If KP is the majority, change HP to KP.

(note that the value of b1 and b2, b3 and b4 etc is always the same, so really only 4 columns need to be looked at, b1, b3, b5, and b7).

To clarify, if the columns are e.g. HP HP CP CP CP CP KP KP, I want to change the two HPs into CPs (and leave the other columns the same).

So, the example I gave would become:

```
 chr <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
    b1 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'KP')
    b2 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'KP')
    b3 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
    b4 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
    b5 <- c('CP', 'CP', 'KP', 'KP', 'CP')
    b6 <- c('CP', 'CP', 'KP', 'KP', 'CP')
    b7 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
    b8 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
    df <- data.frame(chr, b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
    df
```

I have written a function (just for df$b1) with if statements, but it doesn't work.
(note the rules for whether the HP changes to KP or CP depend on how many other CPs or KPs there are):

```
fun <- function(df){

if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'CP' && df$b5 == 'CP' && df$b7 == 'CP') {df$b1 <- 'KP'} 
if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'KP' && df$b5 == 'CP' && df$b7 == 'CP') {df$b1 <- 'CP'}
if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'CP' && df$b5 == 'KP' && df$b7 == 'CP') {df$b1 <- 'CP'}
if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'CP' && df$b5 == 'CP' && df$b7 == 'KP') {df$b1 <- 'CP'}
if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'KP' && df$b5 == 'KP' && df$b7 == 'CP') {df$b1 <- 'KP'} 
if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'KP' && df$b5 == 'CP' && df$b7 == 'KP') {df$b1 <- 'KP'} 
if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'CP' && df$b5 == 'KP' && df$b7 == 'KP') {df$b1 <- 'KP'} 
if(df$b1 == 'HP' && df$b3 == 'KP' && df$b5 == 'KP' && df$b7 == 'KP') {df$b1 <- 'CP'}

df$b2 <-df$b1

}
```

Thanks very much for any help. I'm really stuck on this one.

EDIT: This is a sample of my actual data which is more complex than the example I gave above.

```
structure(list(chr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), pos_c = c(2373L, 2406L, 2418L, 2419L, 
2447L, 2450L, 2468L, 2524L, 2533L, 2535L, 2536L, 2542L, 2623L, 
2709L, 3942L, 11716L, 11893L, 11898L, 12190L, 12396L, 26639L, 
26640L, 26643L, 26646L, 26655L, 26657L, 26661L, 26667L, 26670L, 
26676L, 26679L, 26684L, 26685L, 26688L, 26694L, 26703L, 26710L, 
26712L, 26713L, 26723L, 26733L, 26737L, 26738L, 26739L, 26742L, 
26743L, 26748L, 26761L, 26765L, 26766L, 26778L, 26781L, 26790L, 
26792L, 26796L, 26802L, 26805L, 26811L, 26814L, 26819L, 26820L, 
26823L, 26829L, 26838L, 26846L, 26847L, 26848L, 26872L, 26873L, 
26874L, 26877L, 26878L, 26883L, 26889L, 26901L, 26904L, 26907L, 
26916L, 26923L, 26925L, 26927L, 26931L, 26937L, 26940L, 26946L, 
26954L, 26958L, 26961L, 26963L, 26964L, 26970L, 26981L, 26982L, 
26983L, 26991L, 26994L, 26997L, 27007L, 27008L, 27009L, 27012L, 
27015L, 27018L, 27027L, 202471L, 203660L, 203668L, 203669L, 203670L, 
203672L, 203678L, 203683L, 203686L, 203687L, 203690L, 203704L, 
203705L, 203711L, 203714L, 203732L, 203749L, 203752L, 203754L, 
203755L, 203903L, 203910L, 203911L, 203912L, 203913L, 203914L, 
203915L, 203922L, 203924L, 203933L, 203937L, 203939L, 203945L, 
203948L, 203951L, 203957L, 203960L, 203961L, 203963L, 203969L, 
203972L, 203973L, 203974L, 203975L, 203981L, 203991L, 204220L, 
204227L, 204230L, 204232L, 204242L, 204245L, 204262L, 204272L, 
204278L, 204282L, 204290L), c1 = c(101L, 60L, 63L, 64L, 100L, 
97L, 94L, 83L, 80L, 48L, 46L, 51L, 69L, 46L, 23L, 79L, 63L, 59L, 
53L, 85L, 13L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 
9L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
8L, 39L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 41L, 69L, 79L, 89L, 120L, 128L, 90L, 134L, 
107L, 169L, 120L, 103L, 48L, 58L, 132L, 62L, 19L, 9L, 13L, 12L, 
12L, 17L, 251L, 8L, 367L, 367L, 264L, 5L, 170L, 113L, 234L, 134L, 
143L, 189L, 224L, 255L, 296L, 448L, 239L, 169L, 80L, 312L, 84L, 
403L, 397L, 430L, 529L, 544L, 556L, 565L, 549L, 555L, 4L, 11L, 
0L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 
13L, 14L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 24L, 33L, 33L, 63L, 42L), c2 = c(101L, 
60L, 63L, 64L, 100L, 97L, 94L, 83L, 80L, 48L, 46L, 51L, 69L, 
46L, 23L, 79L, 63L, 59L, 53L, 85L, 13L, 12L, 1L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 
9L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 9L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 39L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 41L, 69L, 79L, 89L, 
120L, 128L, 90L, 134L, 107L, 169L, 120L, 103L, 48L, 58L, 132L, 
62L, 19L, 9L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 17L, 251L, 8L, 367L, 367L, 264L, 
5L, 170L, 113L, 234L, 134L, 143L, 189L, 224L, 255L, 296L, 448L, 
239L, 169L, 80L, 312L, 84L, 403L, 397L, 430L, 529L, 544L, 556L, 
565L, 549L, 555L, 4L, 11L, 0L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 
17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 24L, 
33L, 33L, 63L, 42L), c3 = c(37L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 46L, 46L, 21L, 
26L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 0L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 24L, 32L, 26L, 35L, 32L, 32L, 3L, 
3L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 6L, 81L, 15L, 14L, 
0L, 92L, 157L, 174L, 168L, 236L, 221L, 143L, 228L, 251L, 292L, 
273L, 281L, 33L, 39L, 260L, 57L, 53L, 24L, 22L, 26L, 37L, 37L, 
484L, 16L, 721L, 724L, 436L, 7L, 367L, 163L, 411L, 167L, 373L, 
275L, 599L, 637L, 773L, 866L, 615L, 223L, 63L, 531L, 59L, 878L, 
868L, 911L, 939L, 975L, 995L, 980L, 931L, 958L, 12L, 16L, 0L, 
12L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 
5L, 28L, 3L, 12L, 39L, 40L, 50L, 90L, 80L), c4 = c(37L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 42L, 46L, 46L, 21L, 26L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 29L, 29L, 0L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 24L, 
32L, 26L, 35L, 32L, 32L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 
5L, 11L, 6L, 81L, 15L, 14L, 0L, 92L, 157L, 174L, 168L, 236L, 
221L, 143L, 228L, 251L, 292L, 273L, 281L, 33L, 39L, 260L, 57L, 
53L, 24L, 22L, 26L, 37L, 37L, 484L, 16L, 721L, 724L, 436L, 7L, 
367L, 163L, 411L, 167L, 373L, 275L, 599L, 637L, 773L, 866L, 615L, 
223L, 63L, 531L, 59L, 878L, 868L, 911L, 939L, 975L, 995L, 980L, 
931L, 958L, 12L, 16L, 0L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 
10L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 5L, 28L, 3L, 12L, 39L, 40L, 50L, 
90L, 80L), c5 = c(96L, 77L, 74L, 72L, 96L, 96L, 92L, 80L, 79L, 
79L, 76L, 76L, 66L, 55L, 64L, 78L, 110L, 100L, 165L, 171L, 38L, 
41L, 2L, 38L, 33L, 37L, 21L, 40L, 41L, 21L, 37L, 19L, 45L, 30L, 
22L, 22L, 28L, 34L, 30L, 31L, 25L, 40L, 34L, 33L, 34L, 46L, 41L, 
96L, 48L, 51L, 38L, 93L, 152L, 155L, 155L, 193L, 195L, 189L, 
222L, 213L, 284L, 248L, 230L, 56L, 70L, 208L, 82L, 85L, 67L, 
64L, 64L, 83L, 71L, 495L, 77L, 570L, 577L, 499L, 55L, 292L, 236L, 
352L, 244L, 296L, 351L, 391L, 440L, 483L, 653L, 417L, 194L, 57L, 
460L, 57L, 538L, 520L, 573L, 731L, 753L, 770L, 772L, 757L, 761L, 
35L, 73L, 66L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 70L, 74L, 79L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 69L, 
68L, 71L, 71L, 70L, 73L, 72L, 72L, 74L, 103L, 107L, 106L, 107L, 
109L, 106L, 106L, 105L, 106L, 105L, 108L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 106L, 
103L, 112L, 112L, 113L, 112L, 109L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 120L, 114L, 
97L, 125L, 103L, 124L, 107L, 116L, 145L, 139L, 138L, 177L, 139L
), c6 = c(96L, 77L, 74L, 72L, 96L, 96L, 92L, 80L, 79L, 79L, 76L, 
76L, 66L, 55L, 64L, 78L, 110L, 100L, 165L, 171L, 38L, 41L, 2L, 
38L, 33L, 37L, 21L, 40L, 41L, 21L, 37L, 19L, 45L, 30L, 22L, 22L, 
28L, 34L, 30L, 31L, 25L, 40L, 34L, 33L, 34L, 46L, 41L, 96L, 48L, 
51L, 38L, 93L, 152L, 155L, 155L, 193L, 195L, 189L, 222L, 213L, 
284L, 248L, 230L, 56L, 70L, 208L, 82L, 85L, 67L, 64L, 64L, 83L, 
71L, 495L, 77L, 570L, 577L, 499L, 55L, 292L, 236L, 352L, 244L, 
296L, 351L, 391L, 440L, 483L, 653L, 417L, 194L, 57L, 460L, 57L, 
538L, 520L, 573L, 731L, 753L, 770L, 772L, 757L, 761L, 35L, 73L, 
66L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 70L, 74L, 79L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 69L, 68L, 71L, 
71L, 70L, 73L, 72L, 72L, 74L, 103L, 107L, 106L, 107L, 109L, 106L, 
106L, 105L, 106L, 105L, 108L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 106L, 103L, 112L, 
112L, 113L, 112L, 109L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 120L, 114L, 97L, 125L, 
103L, 124L, 107L, 116L, 145L, 139L, 138L, 177L, 139L), c7 = c(28L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 52L, 50L, 60L, 49L, 50L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 37L, 11L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 28L, 30L, 1L, 17L, 23L, 28L, 11L, 30L, 32L, 
13L, 32L, 19L, 39L, 18L, 17L, 23L, 29L, 46L, 37L, 25L, 21L, 42L, 
32L, 29L, 30L, 41L, 44L, 141L, 72L, 64L, 25L, 93L, 219L, 234L, 
218L, 294L, 277L, 184L, 294L, 273L, 382L, 293L, 280L, 131L, 132L, 
386L, 157L, 99L, 77L, 75L, 68L, 66L, 88L, 615L, 55L, 746L, 740L, 
685L, 27L, 305L, 158L, 511L, 151L, 326L, 371L, 605L, 650L, 727L, 
886L, 623L, 314L, 170L, 734L, 162L, 937L, 908L, 987L, 964L, 997L, 
1002L, 1007L, 960L, 980L, 28L, 75L, 61L, 96L, 98L, 97L, 96L, 
93L, 101L, 99L, 100L, 98L, 91L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 87L, 76L, 75L, 
75L, 76L, 88L, 92L, 87L, 86L, 88L, 87L, 85L, 87L, 87L, 83L, 86L, 
87L, 86L, 86L, 89L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 86L, 83L, 86L, 88L, 87L, 
88L, 84L, 81L, 118L, 90L, 120L, 90L, 101L, 127L, 134L, 140L, 
172L, 160L), c8 = c(28L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 52L, 50L, 60L, 49L, 50L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 37L, 11L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 28L, 30L, 1L, 17L, 
23L, 28L, 11L, 30L, 32L, 13L, 32L, 19L, 39L, 18L, 17L, 23L, 29L, 
46L, 37L, 25L, 21L, 42L, 32L, 29L, 30L, 41L, 44L, 141L, 72L, 
64L, 25L, 93L, 219L, 234L, 218L, 294L, 277L, 184L, 294L, 273L, 
382L, 293L, 280L, 131L, 132L, 386L, 157L, 99L, 77L, 75L, 68L, 
66L, 88L, 615L, 55L, 746L, 740L, 685L, 27L, 305L, 158L, 511L, 
151L, 326L, 371L, 605L, 650L, 727L, 886L, 623L, 314L, 170L, 734L, 
162L, 937L, 908L, 987L, 964L, 997L, 1002L, 1007L, 960L, 980L, 
28L, 75L, 61L, 96L, 98L, 97L, 96L, 93L, 101L, 99L, 100L, 98L, 
91L, 90L, 90L, 89L, 87L, 76L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 88L, 92L, 87L, 86L, 
88L, 87L, 85L, 87L, 87L, 83L, 86L, 87L, 86L, 86L, 89L, 83L, 83L, 
84L, 84L, 86L, 83L, 86L, 88L, 87L, 88L, 84L, 81L, 118L, 90L, 
120L, 90L, 101L, 127L, 134L, 140L, 172L, 160L), k1 = c(39L, 64L, 
68L, 69L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 51L, 54L, 84L, 83L, 84L, 57L, 50L, 43L, 
58L, 72L, 71L, 29L, 35L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 14L, 9L, 15L, 18L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 
27L, 28L, 10L, 28L, 27L, 59L, 64L, 73L, 43L, 19L, 7L, 27L, 5L, 
23L, 30L, 29L, 65L, 10L, 46L, 27L, 160L, 168L, 95L, 175L, 255L, 
265L, 271L, 270L, 76L, 269L, 77L, 14L, 12L, 11L, 118L, 382L, 
204L, 220L, 181L, 290L, 290L, 114L, 209L, 89L, 159L, 7L, 144L, 
95L, 9L, 180L, 411L, 105L, 125L, 97L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 
540L, 1L, 32L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 18L, 17L, 8L, 18L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 21L, 28L, 49L, 50L, 54L, 45L, 
44L), k2 = c(39L, 64L, 68L, 69L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 51L, 54L, 84L, 
83L, 84L, 57L, 50L, 43L, 58L, 72L, 71L, 29L, 35L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 14L, 9L, 
15L, 18L, 24L, 20L, 20L, 27L, 28L, 10L, 28L, 27L, 59L, 64L, 73L, 
43L, 19L, 7L, 27L, 5L, 23L, 30L, 29L, 65L, 10L, 46L, 27L, 160L, 
168L, 95L, 175L, 255L, 265L, 271L, 270L, 76L, 269L, 77L, 14L, 
12L, 11L, 118L, 382L, 204L, 220L, 181L, 290L, 290L, 114L, 209L, 
89L, 159L, 7L, 144L, 95L, 9L, 180L, 411L, 105L, 125L, 97L, 19L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 540L, 1L, 32L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 
14L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 9L, 18L, 17L, 8L, 18L, 
6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 21L, 
28L, 49L, 50L, 54L, 45L, 44L), k3 = c(84L, 122L, 120L, 120L, 
92L, 88L, 90L, 107L, 98L, 114L, 120L, 117L, 91L, 64L, 59L, 100L, 
113L, 109L, 56L, 136L, 1L, 0L, 29L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 
7L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 44L, 46L, 38L, 51L, 60L, 79L, 75L, 80L, 
83L, 80L, 41L, 97L, 61L, 133L, 135L, 180L, 100L, 50L, 28L, 75L, 
18L, 79L, 94L, 100L, 117L, 47L, 74L, 68L, 393L, 390L, 191L, 416L, 
504L, 532L, 545L, 545L, 181L, 556L, 175L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 312L, 
766L, 389L, 416L, 418L, 639L, 475L, 239L, 293L, 70L, 135L, 37L, 
122L, 84L, 42L, 408L, 886L, 93L, 115L, 65L, 67L, 35L, 37L, 47L, 
50L, 54L, 942L, 9L, 43L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 32L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 30L, 26L, 23L, 24L, 23L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 65L, 73L, 111L, 98L, 
133L, 107L, 64L), k4 = c(84L, 122L, 120L, 120L, 92L, 88L, 90L, 
107L, 98L, 114L, 120L, 117L, 91L, 64L, 59L, 100L, 113L, 109L, 
56L, 136L, 1L, 0L, 29L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 11L, 
7L, 10L, 9L, 44L, 46L, 38L, 51L, 60L, 79L, 75L, 80L, 83L, 80L, 
41L, 97L, 61L, 133L, 135L, 180L, 100L, 50L, 28L, 75L, 18L, 79L, 
94L, 100L, 117L, 47L, 74L, 68L, 393L, 390L, 191L, 416L, 504L, 
532L, 545L, 545L, 181L, 556L, 175L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 312L, 766L, 
389L, 416L, 418L, 639L, 475L, 239L, 293L, 70L, 135L, 37L, 122L, 
84L, 42L, 408L, 886L, 93L, 115L, 65L, 67L, 35L, 37L, 47L, 50L, 
54L, 942L, 9L, 43L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
32L, 33L, 32L, 33L, 30L, 26L, 23L, 24L, 23L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 65L, 73L, 111L, 98L, 
133L, 107L, 64L), k5 = c(0L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 18L, 15L, 0L, 2L, 38L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 21L, 2L, 15L, 1L, 26L, 22L, 17L, 
27L, 33L, 41L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 51L, 14L, 50L, 31L, 82L, 84L, 108L, 
55L, 24L, 16L, 51L, 33L, 44L, 55L, 54L, 87L, 15L, 20L, 27L, 285L, 
297L, 151L, 293L, 343L, 363L, 374L, 376L, 57L, 382L, 24L, 25L, 
10L, 8L, 103L, 551L, 301L, 320L, 276L, 364L, 340L, 49L, 272L, 
171L, 195L, 24L, 180L, 161L, 11L, 254L, 663L, 188L, 229L, 158L, 
26L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 708L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 43L, 50L, 78L, 75L, 
87L, 78L, 59L), k6 = c(0L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 18L, 15L, 0L, 2L, 38L, 3L, 
5L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 21L, 2L, 15L, 1L, 26L, 22L, 17L, 
27L, 33L, 41L, 39L, 42L, 45L, 51L, 14L, 50L, 31L, 82L, 84L, 108L, 
55L, 24L, 16L, 51L, 33L, 44L, 55L, 54L, 87L, 15L, 20L, 27L, 285L, 
297L, 151L, 293L, 343L, 363L, 374L, 376L, 57L, 382L, 24L, 25L, 
10L, 8L, 103L, 551L, 301L, 320L, 276L, 364L, 340L, 49L, 272L, 
171L, 195L, 24L, 180L, 161L, 11L, 254L, 663L, 188L, 229L, 158L, 
26L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 708L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 43L, 50L, 78L, 75L, 
87L, 78L, 59L), k7 = c(0L, 36L, 42L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 158L, 0L, 1L, 28L, 
14L, 11L, 9L, 27L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 28L, 14L, 32L, 19L, 41L, 
37L, 26L, 39L, 57L, 85L, 75L, 82L, 87L, 87L, 37L, 91L, 54L, 124L, 
138L, 206L, 150L, 44L, 18L, 92L, 38L, 76L, 95L, 101L, 155L, 20L, 
90L, 48L, 375L, 344L, 135L, 379L, 519L, 537L, 549L, 563L, 67L, 
557L, 91L, 43L, 30L, 35L, 125L, 784L, 491L, 519L, 324L, 627L, 
503L, 215L, 296L, 68L, 203L, 42L, 173L, 58L, 43L, 222L, 812L, 
64L, 98L, 36L, 65L, 36L, 45L, 42L, 50L, 43L, 962L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 25L, 
27L, 8L, 26L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
9L, 3L, 59L, 77L, 123L, 107L, 144L, 119L, 79L), k8 = c(0L, 36L, 
42L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 31L, 158L, 0L, 1L, 28L, 14L, 11L, 9L, 27L, 14L, 12L, 
14L, 14L, 28L, 14L, 32L, 19L, 41L, 37L, 26L, 39L, 57L, 85L, 75L, 
82L, 87L, 87L, 37L, 91L, 54L, 124L, 138L, 206L, 150L, 44L, 18L, 
92L, 38L, 76L, 95L, 101L, 155L, 20L, 90L, 48L, 375L, 344L, 135L, 
379L, 519L, 537L, 549L, 563L, 67L, 557L, 91L, 43L, 30L, 35L, 
125L, 784L, 491L, 519L, 324L, 627L, 503L, 215L, 296L, 68L, 203L, 
42L, 173L, 58L, 43L, 222L, 812L, 64L, 98L, 36L, 65L, 36L, 45L, 
42L, 50L, 43L, 962L, 0L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 25L, 27L, 8L, 26L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 59L, 77L, 123L, 107L, 
144L, 119L, 79L), b1 = structure(c(7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
3L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("CP", "HF", 
"HP", "KF", "KP", "NF", "NP"), class = "factor"), b2 = structure(c(7L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L
), .Label = c("CP", "HF", "HP", "KF", "KP", "NF", "NP"), class = "factor"), 
    b3 = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
    3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
    6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
    7L), .Label = c("CP", "HF", "HP", "KF", "KP", "NF", "NP"), class = "factor"), 
    b4 = structure(c(3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
    3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
    6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
    7L), .Label = c("CP", "HF", "HP", "KF", "KP", "NF", "NP"), class = "factor"), 
    b5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    4L), .Label = c("CP", "HP", "KP", "NP"), class = "factor"), 
    b6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    4L), .Label = c("CP", "HP", "KP", "NP"), class = "factor"), 
    b7 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
    6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
    3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
    6L), .Label = c("CF", "CP", "HP", "KP", "NF", "NP"), class = "factor"), 
    b8 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
    6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 
    3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
    6L), .Label = c("CF", "CP", "HP", "KP", "NF", "NP"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("chr", 
"pos_c", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "k1", 
"k2", "k3", "k4", "k5", "k6", "k7", "k8", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", 
"b5", "b6", "b7", "b8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-161L))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected result

Comment: Sure, it should look like this: 'chr <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
b1 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'KP')
b2 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'KP')
b3 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
b4 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
b5 <- c('CP', 'CP', 'KP', 'KP', 'CP')
b6 <- c('CP', 'CP', 'KP', 'KP', 'CP')
b7 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
b8 <- c('CP', 'KP', 'CP', 'CP', 'CP')
df <- data.frame(chr, b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
df'

Comment: Please update it in your post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
t(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(rg){
                occ_rg <- table(rg)
                rg[grep("HP",rg)] <- names(occ_rg)[which.max(occ_rg)]
                return(rg)}))
```

*So, to have your new df:*

```
df <- data.frame(chr=df[, 1], t(apply(df[,-1], 1, function(rg){
                                                  occ_rg <- table(rg)
                                                  rg[grep("HP",rg)] <- names(occ_rg)[which.max(occ_rg)]
                                                  return(rg)})), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
#  chr b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8
#1   1 CP CP CP CP CP CP CP CP
#2   1 KP KP KP KP CP CP KP KP
#3   1 CP CP CP CP KP KP CP CP
#4   1 CP CP CP CP KP KP CP CP
#5   1 KP KP CP CP CP CP CP CP
```

**EDIT**

If you have other columns and the columns you want to change are the only ones beginning with "b", you can do :

```
df[, grepl("^b", colnames(df))] <- t(apply(df[, grepl("^b", colnames(df))], 
                                           1, 
                                           function(rg){
                                                   occ_rg <- table(rg)
                                                   rg[grep("HP",rg)] <- names(occ_rg)[which.max(occ_rg)]
                                                   return(rg)}))
```

***Example:***

With this df:

```
#  chr c1 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 c2
#1   1  1 HP HP CP CP CP CP CP CP 11
#2   1  2 HP HP KP KP CP CP KP KP 12
#3   1  3 CP CP CP CP KP KP HP HP 13
#4   1  4 CP CP HP HP KP KP CP CP 14
#5   1  5 KP KP CP CP HP HP CP CP 15
```

You get:

```
#  chr c1 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 c2
#1   1  1 CP CP CP CP CP CP CP CP 11
#2   1  2 KP KP KP KP CP CP KP KP 12
#3   1  3 CP CP CP CP KP KP CP CP 13
#4   1  4 CP CP CP CP KP KP CP CP 14
#5   1  5 KP KP CP CP CP CP CP CP 15
```

**EDIT 2**

If you have other values than "HP", "CP" and "KP" and want to replace "HP" by either "CP" or "KP", depending on which occurs the most, you can do:

```
df[, grepl("^b", colnames(df))] <- t(apply(df[, grepl("^b", colnames(df))], 
                                           1, 
                                           function(rg){
                                                   occ_rg <- table(rg)
                                                   occ_rg <- occ_rg[grepl("KP|CP", names(occ_rg))]
                                                   rg[grep("HP",rg)] <- names(occ_rg)[which.max(occ_rg)]
                                                   return(rg)}))
```

***Explanation (for edit2):***

```
df[, grepl("^b", colnames(df))] <- # only the columns beginning with b are considered (so the other ones will remain untouched)

      t( # the results of apply will be transposed
         apply(df[, grepl("^b", colnames(df))], # apply on df with only the columns beginning by b
               1, # by row
               function(rg){ # a function that takes a vector "rg" as input
                   occ_rg <- table(rg) # computes the table
                   occ_rg <- occ_rg[grepl("KP|CP", names(occ_rg))] # keep only the occurrences of either "KP" or "CP"
                   rg[grep("HP",rg)] <- names(occ_rg)[which.max(occ_rg)] # replace in the vector rg the "HP" elements by "KP" or "CP" depending on which occurs the most
                   return(rg) # finally returns the vector rg
               }))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It works perfectly on the example dataset, but on my real dataset, it only works if the 'HP's are in b1 and b2. If they are in the other columns, they are replaced with 0. In the example dataset I omitted a number of irrelevant columns to simply the question. Can your code be adapted for a dataset with more columns? I guess it would be a case of changing `df[, 1]` ?

Comment: you can put the numbers of the columns that are the relevant ones in the `apply` call : instead of `df[, -1]`, put df[, num_of_relevant_col]`, for example `df[, c(2:5,8:10)]` if the bxx columns are the 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10th columns

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. However, in the final dataframe all the columns except the 'b' columns and 'chr' are removed. I can add them back in again from the original dataframe but I guess there's a better way?

Comment: yes, you can put in the last call, instead of `df <- data.frame(chr=df[, 1], t(apply...)`, `df[,  num_of_relevant_col] <- t(apply(...))`. Are the relevant columns the only one beginning by "b" ?

Comment: @Margins, I've edited my answer to modify only the "relevant" columns, based on the fact that they are the only ones beginning with "b". Let me know if it now works or if you need other changes.

Comment: happy to hear! :-) you're welcome, thanks for your feedback on my edit

Comment: Actually, I have one more question... what if there are other possible values other than HP, CP and KP, but you only want to change the HPs into the maximum out of KP and CP? So if the most common string in a line is something else (my dataset also has KF, CF, NF, NP, HF), ignore that and go to whichever is most common out of KP and CP.

Comment: @Margins, well, for that, you have to modify the answer  ;-). That's why it is better to try to put all "information" in your initial question, so the answer totally fulfill your needs. I'll make an "EDIT2"

Comment: @Margins, see my EDIT2, let me know if it works the way you want it to

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried to simplify the question too much originally. I think you are missing a bracket here: occ_rg <- occ_rg[grepl("KP|CP", names(occ_rg)]. But even with the bracket I get the error 'replacement has length zero'.

Comment: @Margins, thanks for your comment, there was indeed a missing `)`, sorry for that. However, I do get the expected result once the typo corrected. Can you please `dput` your original data (or a representative sample of it if it's too big) ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I have added it to my initial post. I haven't used dput before so I hope it works!

Comment: sorry to bring this up again after a month but I was just trying to fix the code myself and realised I don't understand enough about how it works. But I think the problem is that when there is a row with a 'HP' but NO 'CP's or 'KP's, then the 'replacement has length zero'. So, only rows with at least one HP and at least one KP or CP need to be loked at. In the long term though it would be really really helpful if you could explain how your code works as I might need to modify it more in the future and don't want to keep bothering you with it!

Comment: @Margins, yes, sorry I didn't explain my code. I'll edit to comment on the last edit (edit2), you'll let me know if you solved your issue or if you need help

Comment: Thanks very much for that! To fix the error I was getting before ('Error in rg[grep("HP", rg)] <- names(occ_rg [which.max(occ_rg)] : replacement has length zero', I changed the offending line to this: ifelse(names(occ_rg)[which.max(occ_rg)]!=0,  rg[grep("HP",rg)] <- names(occ_rg)[which.max(occ_rg)], rg[grep("HP",rg)] <- 'NP'). This may not be a very elegant solution but it seems to have fixed it!